# CSS Variable with HSL not recalculating

Tags: nested, css-variables, hsl

### Situation

I have the following definitions (simplified) in my CSS file.

```css
:root {
  --app-color-hue: 30;
  --app-color: hsl(var(--app-color-hue), 80%, 60%);
}

body {
  --app-color-hue: 145;
  background: var(--app-color);
}
```

I was expecting to use the CSS variable `app-color` throughout my application and set the hue through `--app-color-hue`. However, the `body` element shows up **Orange (30)** instead of **Green (145)**.

When I set the `hsl` myself in the value, the color updates just fine.

```css
body {
  background: hsl(var(--app-color-hue), 80%, 60%);
}
```

<sub>Codepen: https://codepen.io/Dyljyn/pen/BaNVwqE</sub>

---

### Possible explanation

I'm assuming the problem is that `hsl` does detect the change and does not recalculate when a CSS variable inside it is updated in another element.

### Question

Does anyone have more insight on this matter?

I also don't know how I can report this as a bug if it is considered a bug. So I'd also appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

> Custom properties are scoped to the element(s) they are declared on,
>   and participate in the cascade: the value of such a custom property is
>   that from the declaration decided by the cascading algorithm.
>   
> <sub>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*</sub>

So my "possible explanation" is by design and therefor not a bug.